# The command "COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS=1 composer install" failed error when running laravel vapor deploy

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-vapor

I'm developing an application using the latest Laravel 7 along with deploying to AWS using Vapor. I'm on Windows 10 environment.

When running the following command to deploy to staging `vendor/bin/vapor deploy` I get the following error.

```
In Process.php line 252:

  The command "COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS=1 composer install" failed.

  Exit Code: 1(General error)

  Working directory: C:\Users\Matthew Wallace\Development\web\615ioDemos/.vap
  or/build/app

  Output:
  ================


  Error Output:
  ================
  'COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS' is not recognized as an internal or external c
  ommand,
  operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution for this problem was to open the vapor.yml and modify the composer install lines in the `build:` sections for staging and production by removing 'COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS=1'

This is what my build section looks like now.

```
build:
    - 'composer install'
    - 'php artisan event:cache'
    - 'npm ci && npm run dev && rm -rf node_modules'
```

Answer (score 3):

*The answer above is just partly a fix.* (answ by @mattwallace)

The whole story:

1. Remove `COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS=1` in **vapor.yml**
2. Add in **composer.json** under *config*: `"COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS": true`

**More details:**

You'll probably run into problems while attaching a database to your app while working on Win (at least I did :P).

The issue is with the strategy of resolving paths. By default the strategy is set to "**symlink**" - I assume the more appropriate way would be to set this to "**mirror**", as we build the project locally and move the content on a different host (filesystem structure etc.).

The error above is just the terminal/powershell not knowing how to handle the first param in the command line - `COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS` - it still needs to be set up.

More about the param [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-mirror-path-repos).

In the docs you can find:

> You can set a number of environment variables that override certain settings. Whenever possible it is recommended to specify these settings in the config section of composer.json instead.

There you go:

```json
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS": true
},
```

Comment: Seems like they changed it that you need to use docker now: The "separate-vendor" option is deprecated. Please use Docker based deployments instead: https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/environments.html#runtime

Answer (score 2):

As our team also face this issue, and we need to use in multiple projects, we made a command that is accessible in a package.
Just install and do simple setup will do

https://packagist.org/packages/stephenkhoo/laravel-vapor-deploy-helper

`composer require stephenkhoo/laravel-vapor-deploy-helper`

Update your vapor.yml from

```yaml
build:
    - 'COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS=1 composer install --no-dev'
```

to

```yaml
build:
    - 'php artisan build:composer-mirror'
    - 'composer install --no-dev'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following line causes the issue:

```
'COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS=1 composer install --no-dev'
```

It's a script that can run on `bash`. It basically sets an environment variable, then calls `composer` with some options and parameters. If your operating system is Windows, you will need the counterpart syntax in `cmd`, which can be as follows:

```
'set COMPOSER_MIRROR_PATH_REPOS=1 & composer install --no-dev'
```